# PowerShell Get-WinEvent Data Query

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Trying to write a script to retrieve all the details for events being triggered for a certain issue.

The events that have been seen within the event viewer have no Event ID's etc. that would help to filter the results.

The only data I can potential use is contained within the EventData section with "Married"

```
Get-WinEvent @{LogName='Application';Level=2} | Where {$_.ProviderName -eq 'BizTalk Server' -and $_.Message -contains 'Marri'}
```

I'm not sure if the `$_.Message` is looking at the EventData section.. any advice?

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to just take a sample to see if you are looking at the right field? Or export a few sample eventlogs to a csv with `get-Winevent Application | Select-object -property *`. That would let you examine the results and determine the right fields

Comment: typo: replace '[' bracket with '{' bracket and add '}' bracket in the end 'Marri'}

Comment: @VincentK Thank you for the typo [corrected]

Comment: @RohinSidharth I've tried what you suggested but the data is not present using that suggestion to ensure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't a fully working solution but it should give you an output of data that provides you with insight on what to use.
I can't really do it for you completely because i don't have the data to test with.

```
    $events = Get-WinEvent  -FilterHashTable @{LogName = "Application";Level=2} -MaxEvents 50 | where {$_.Message -like '*'}

    foreach($event in $events){
    "-"*150

             $eventXML = [xml]$event.ToXml()
             #if there is data in the XML
             if($eventXML.Event.EventData.data -like '*Marri*'){
                $event.Message
                $event | gm
                write-host $event
                write-host $eventXML.Event.EventData.data -ForegroundColor Green
             }
    "-"*150
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I shall give it a try could you explain what ""-"*150" does ?

Comment: It just repeats the symbol '-' 150 times, so it draws a line.
I do that to make clear what each iteration shows and separates them. It serves no further purpose other than that.

Comment: Thanks that has worked, I can see some green and a load of - and some Method and property details. I'm looking for a count / date time on those events to try and understand more information about those errors to pass on for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean with the count /date time part.
you could display the time and provider so:

```
 
    $events = Get-WinEvent  -FilterHashTable @{LogName = "Application";Level=2} -MaxEvents 50 |
    where {$_.Message -like '*'}
```

```
foreach($event in $events){
"-"*50                        
            $event.TimeCreated
            $event.ProviderName
            $event.Message             
"-"*50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where in eventdata "married" is, but in powershell 6 you can do something like this and use -filterhashtable on eventdata named data fields.  Providername can be in the hashtable as well.

```
Get-WinEvent @{LogName='Application'; Level=2; 
  providername='biztalk server'; status='married'}
```

An example that works for me:

```
get-winevent @{ logname = 'application'; param2 = 'suppressduplicateduration' }
```